# How do you translate "on it", "onto it", "in it", and "into it" in conversational German?

Tags: english-to-german

Suppose a person is walking toward a road. Right before she steps onto the road, she points at the road and says, "I walk onto it." As she continues walking on the road, she points down at the road and says, "I walk on it."

Question: can both of her statements be translated to: "Ich laufe darauf." ? If not, then what are the correct ways to say these sentences?

Similarly, suppose a person is walking toward a cave. Right before she steps into the cave, she points at the cave and says, "I walk into it." As she continues walking in the cave, she says, "I walk in it."

Question: can both of her statements be translated to: "Ich laufe darin." ? If not, then what are the correct ways to say these sentences?

I am looking for everyday conversational usage. Thanks!

Comment: The former one can indeed be ambiguous. But if I were to say that, I'd probably differentiate the two use cases by saying either "Ich laufe nun/jetzt dadrauf" (onto) or "Ich laufe grad dadrauf" (on it). An unambiguous variation for "onto" would be "Ich werde nun/jetzt dadrauf laufen". — It should also be mentioned that when not using the  adverb (i.e. saying "auf die/der Straße"), the grammatical case is the key to understanding it.

Comment: What Em1 said at the end; the literal translations would be _ich gehe auf **sie** [rauf]_ (onto) and _ich gehe auf **ihr**_ (assuming reference to _die Straße_) or _ich gehe in **sie** [rein]_ and _ich gehe in **ihr**_ (_die Höhle_). The other direction would yield _I run thereon_ and _I run therein_ (or _I’m running ~_). There are also often unambiguous lexemic alternatives in both languages, e.g. _ich betrete sie_ (_I enter it_) or _ich steige darauf_ (_I step onto it_).

Answer (score 1):

*darauf* is more ambiguous.

To be emphatic you can say:

- *“Ich laufe (da) hinauf / herauf / 'rauf.”*  (onto)
- *“Ich laufe dadrauf/hierdrauf.”* (on top of)

But ‘going into something’ is *darein*, not *darin*.

Also, colloquially it is common to say *“Ich bin dadrin”* (in there). It has a slightly different emphasis than *“Ich bin drin”* (inside).

Comment: See if I have this straight:
_darauf_ can mean "on it" or "onto it" depending on the context.
_darein_ means "into it".
_darin_ means "in it".

Are these correct?

Comment: Yes. There are others that do not match. *Wo**her** kommst Du? Ich komme *aus* München. Gehst Du **zur** / **in** die Schule? Ich gege da**hin**."

Comment: I think it's fair to say that in colloquial (but not dialect, just Prussian city folk ;-)) it is generally: *Bin drauf*, *Geh rauf*, *Bin drin.* / *Geh rein*, *Bin dran.* / *Geh ran* etc. (*Drin* / *rein* is an exception but still follows that pattern.). And only *in* *auf* *an* have multiple possible cases.

Comment: Thank you. I talked to a friend who has a concern about _darin_. Can you verify that _darin_ can be used in the manner described in my main question (i.e., walking in a cave, swimming in a river)?

Comment: Yes: *Ich laufe in einer Höhle.  Ich laufe hierin/darin.  Ich schwimme in einem Fluss.  Ich schwimme hierin/darin.*  It is much like older English (*therein*).  (See examples at http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/darin)

Comment: If the confusion is that there is movement, that is another issue.  It's not movement per se that requires accusative.  (*Ich tanze in der Disko.* (in) vs *Ich tanze in die Disko (hinein).* (into))

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I have a follow-up question. Can _hinein_ be used instead of _darein_? Can I say "Ich laufe hinein" when walking into a cave? Can I say "Ich springe hinein" when jumping into a river?

Comment: Yes. I would have to think long to explain the nuance in English. If it helps, literally speaking *hin* in English is *hither*. It's possible that *hinein* in practice is simply more formal, more poetic or more Southern. In any case Southerners tend to say *'nein* where Northerners say *'rein*.

Comment: It's not about meaning but about emphasis.  *"Schmeiss hinein!  Nein, nicht darein, hierein.*  What are you working on, some sort of missile research? ;-)

Comment: Thank you. The reason I asked about _hinein_ is because it seems that it is much more commonly used than _darein_ (or is this statement not correct because of what you said re: Southerners vs Northerners?). I understand that _hinein_ is used for movement away from the speaker's location, and _herein_ is used for movement toward the speaker's location (both cases are meant to translate "into it"). If that is correct so far, then what does a person say when she observes something moving into something else and does not want to reference her own location?

Comment: Based on your example (_Schmeiss hinein! Nein, nicht darein, hierein._), it seems that _darein_ would be what a person would say if she does not want to reference her own location. Is that correct?

Comment: Consciously at least I would never have thought of it in those terms.  *darein* is just emphatic.  *hinein* is no less vague with regard to speaker's location.

Comment: If the relationship between _darein_ and _hinein_ is that the former is more emphatic than the latter, then what is the relationship between those two and _herein_?

Comment: *Herein* and *darein* are both emphatic, if something is very near it sounds odd to say *darein*.

Comment: And pardon, there is no *hierein*, only *hier 'rein* and *herein*.  As you see I am the wrong guy to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Both "I walk onto it" and "I walk on it" would usually be translated to "Ich laufe darauf" (formal) or "Ich laufe drauf" (informal). How the informal version is written and pronounced depends on the German dialect which is spoken.

Answer (score 1):

*In*, *an*, *auf*, *über*, *unter*, ... are used both for location and direction. 
Without seeing the case (Akk/Dat), things may easily become ambiguous. 
So in German you have to say at least "*Ich laufe auf sie*" or "*Ich laufe auf ihr*", because *laufen* allows both cases. But as stand-alone sentences, they sound very poor, almost like babytalk.

The prefixes *hin*- and *her*- clearly indicate a direction; *hin*- points away from, *her*- approaches the 'center of action' (rather than the speaker's location). Note, that there is no *hinin* or *herin*, but the words *hinein* and *herein* fill that gap well.
So you can also say "*Ich gehe hinauf*" and "*Ich gehe hinein*". 
Though *hinauf* implies upward movement and sounds odd for a road.

The prefix *dar*- is more unspecific. When in doubt, I'd read it as a location rather than a direction, but this is probably my personal perception.
Anyway this prefix is good style, as long as the meaning is clear:
"*Darauf warte ich*", "*Darin sind wir uns einig*", "*Darüber muß ich nachdenken*", "*Darunter kann ich mir nichts vorstellen*". (Uneducated people would say: "*Auf das warte ich*", "*In dem*...", "*Über das*...", "*Unter dem*...").

Exception: while *darin* is commonly used figuratively,
*[da] drin[nen]* is the everyday's choice when speaking about locations: "*Da ist viel Milch drin*", "*Hier drinnen ist's schön warm*". Nobody says "*Darin ist viel Milch*" or "*Darin ist es warm*". That's only for writing.

For your question, I'd suggest:

- "Ich betrete sie" (or "Ich laufe auf die Straße", repeating the noun)
- "Ich laufe darauf [herum]" (or "Ich laufe auf der Straße")
- "Ich laufe hinein"
- "Ich laufe in ihr umher" (avoid stopping with *ihr*)

You see, that I avoid "*auf ihr*" and "*in ihr*". My gut feelings are, that these sentences end too abruptly: one expects something like "*auf ihr...em Belag*" or "*in ihr...em Inneren*". But "*auf ihm*" (*dem Weg*) would be fine.

Similar, "*auf sie*" (also "*in sie*") may be mistaken as "on her", "on them", or "on You", confusing the listener. "*Ich steh' auf sie*", "*Ich höre auf Sie*", and "*Auf sie mit Gebrüll!*" are absolutely fine; but with *laufen*, it takes a second to recognize the 3rd person singular femininum accusative pronoun.

---

Conclusion:

- Your sentences are grammatically correct; just a little ambiguous or irritating.
- Educated speakers prefer *hinauf* to "*auf ihn/sie/es*"; same with *her*- and *dar*-.
- Disambiguation is best done by choosing a more specific verb (*betreten*, *umherlaufen*).